# DHCP server only works one time

Tags: dhcp

I installed e configured the DHCP server and removed all network-manager*.

All my settings are just like this one:
[dhcpd fails to start on eth1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57155/dhcpd-fails-to-start-on-eth1)
(but i use eth0)

I do:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

Then plug the cable between the server and the client.
The client receives the correct IP address: 192-168.0.50

BUT, if I unplug the cable and put it back the Client doesn't receive a valid IP address.
I have to make **sudo ifdown eth0**, **sudo ifup eth0** at the server to the client receive a valid IP address again.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT: my current configuration files are:**

```
$ cat /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

,

```
$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
ddns-update-style none;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  interface eth0;
  range 192.168.0.50 192.168.0.100;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
  option routers 192.168.0.1;
}
```

,

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast   192.168.0.255
#gateway    192.168.0.1
```

,

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

I'm not using any router or switch. Just two PCs connected my cable.
After rebooting the server, i have to

```
$ sudo isc-dhcp-server start
```

After this the client PC obtains a correct IP.
BUT if I unplug the cable and connect it again, it won't get an IP in the correct range.
I have to ifdown and then ifup eth0.

Answer (score 2):

If you removed or disabled NetworkManager you need to configure networking manually.

1) Add your nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

```
# change '192.168.0.1' to the nameserver you want to use.
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

2) Bring your network down.

```
sudo service networking stop
```

3) Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/network/interfaces

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add in your configuration for eth0. With DHCP it is short.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

4) Bring your network up

```
sudo service networking start
```

dhcp / networking should then work properly when you re-boot.

Comment: I forget the nameserver at resolv.conf. But It's not from that...
(I updated my first post)

Comment: That network configuration is using a static ip, not dhcp. I assume your router is 192.168.0.1, if so, and if you use a static address, you should probably not use "address 192.168.0.1"